# System.Numerics.Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated = false when using ngen.exe

Tags: .net, ngen

System.Numerics.Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated is set to true when I debug my application in Visual Studio.

If i install my program and run ngen.exe (Native Image Generator) to speedup startup then System.Numerics.Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated is always false.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install "C:\Program Files\App\app.exe"

Is there something I can do to enable IsHardwareAccelerated while still using ngen to speedup application startup?

Comment: Hard to imagine how you could get false, surely you saw the "Target-dependent SIMD vector types may not be used with ngen" messages when you tried it?  Move that code into another assembly so your main code can still be ngened, perhaps.

Comment: I do not get that warning. The dll that contains vector code does not seem to be ngen'd but I do the check for IsHardwareAccelerated in the main exe so I guess that explains why it is false.

Can IsHardwareAccelerated be different in every loaded dll?